# Hbase Can not put 8th row

Tags: hbase, put

I used apache Hbase 2.3.5 to build a database. I can insert 7 rows successfully. but when i try to insert 8th raw , throw a error
"hbase(main):096:0> put 'Car', 008 , 'car:color','red'
SyntaxError: (hbase):96: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
put 'Car', 008 , 'car:color','red' "

```html
hbase(main):100:0> create 'Car','car'
Created table Car
Took 0.6730 seconds
=> Hbase::Table - Car
hbase(main):101:0> put 'Car', 001 , 'car:color','red'
Took 0.0290 seconds
hbase(main):102:0> put 'Car', 002 , 'car:color','white'
Took 0.0060 seconds
hbase(main):103:0> put 'Car', 003 , 'car:color','gray'
Took 0.0040 seconds
hbase(main):104:0> put 'Car', 004 , 'car:color','blue'
Took 0.0040 seconds
hbase(main):105:0> put 'Car', 005 , 'car:color','yellow'
Took 0.0040 seconds
hbase(main):106:0> put 'Car', 006 , 'car:color','orange'
Took 0.0050 seconds
hbase(main):107:0> put 'Car', 007 , 'car:color','black'
Took 0.0040 seconds
hbase(main):108:0> put 'Car', 008 , 'car:color','red'
SyntaxError: (hbase):108: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER
put 'Car', 008 , 'car:color','red'
```

[this is a image of command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCuie.png)

please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get this weird error because you start your row key with `0` and it is interpreted as octal i.e. you can use numbers `0-7` as digits not `8`